# how to save dynamically created objects using NSCoding and NSFileManager

Tags: ios

is there any way to save dynamically created objects.

i am using NSCoding & NSFileManager to save data of players and there score and its working fine

but now my requirement is to save game state in that there are lot of dynamically created objects and i want to save all those objects

actually i am creating similar objects at regular interval(not creating all objects initially)
i.e i am doing similar to tetris game, that is if one object reaches to floor/gound we have to generate  another object like that

now i want to save all the objects which are created and its positions.

please give me some suggestion to save all objects which are created dynamically

Comment: Aren't (pretty much) all objects created dynamically? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googles first hit: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager
You have to create an object containing your game state including position and state of all your game blocks and stuff. This object needs to be saved using the mechanism you already implemented for your player.

Comment: hi michael thank u for your reply.i saved all my game data by taking your suggestion and raywenderlich example as reference